# Display Mongoid localized field

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I have a Mongoid field that's localized, achieved via:

`field :name, localize: true`

It has both a `en` version and a `de` version. Is there a way I can output both locals on the same View? Something like this in HAML, but displaying `en` and `de` versions.

`= user.name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get and set all the translations at once by using the corresponding **_translations** method.

You can do this for each language in **config.i18n.available_locales = [:de, :en]** :

```
- I18n.available_locales.each do |language|
  = @user.name_translations[language.to_s]
```

or just:

```
= @user.name_translations['en']
= @user.name_translations['de']
```

It's described there http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/documents.html#localized_fields

Comment: setting in this format:
`@user.name_translations['de']`
didn't work for me.
Only with _translations, but I really need to set only a signle locale

Comment: You can change locale then set value:
I18n.locale = :de        
@user.name = 'name in de'
You can also cache current locale before it, then restore it after